# Get the type of file from IPFS hash/URL in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, types, ipfs

I am trying to create an IPFS hash viewer on my website.

I have tried many different node npm packages but they don't quite get the right info I am looking for/need.

I want to display the IPFS correctly if it is text, image or video or other.

I first need to detect the filetype/content-type/MIME type
(i am not 100% sure  what it is called honestly)

What is the right way to do this?

I want to be able to use an if statement based on what the type of file it is and either use an "embed", "img src", "JSON Parse" or just display basic text.

I would appreciate any tips, thanks!